# Finding value of binary tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree

Code given:

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a | Branch b [Tree a b] deriving (Eq,Read,Show)
```

--with these trees defines

```
t1 = Branch "+" [Leaf 10, Leaf 20, Branch "*" [Leaf 2, Leaf 3, Leaf 4], Leaf 50]

t2 = Branch "*" [t1,t1,t1] //should multiply t1 3 times
```

How can I find the value of t1? As in, 10 + 20 + (2 * 3 * 4) + 50 = 104

I've started a solve function:

```
solve (Leaf a) = a 
solve (Branch _ ts) = //not sure how to make it solve itself recursively here.
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you want a solution in C#; don't edit this question to change its meaning, since it already has answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just call `solve` recursively. And you may as well create your own type for your operators instead of using strings.

```
data Op = Plus | Mult

solve :: Tree Int Op -> Int
solve (Leaf a) = a
solve (Branch Plus args) = sum (map solve args)
solve (Branch Mult args) = product (map solve args)
```

Comment: Is `prod` a typo of `product`?

Comment: Great answer. I understand so much more clearly. Could you elaborate more on what you mean about operators? and what is the data Op = Plus | Mult you included?

Comment: @user3487386 `data Op = ...` is a data type definition, just like your `data Tree a b = ...`, you could use it to indicate which operation you want to perform, just like you use `"+"` and `"*"` to indicate the same thing, but the operation type makes the implementation of `solve` much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a
              | Branch b [Tree a b]
              deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

t1 = Branch '+' [Leaf 10, Leaf 20, Branch '*' [Leaf 2, Leaf 3, Leaf 4], Leaf 50]
t2 = Branch '*' [t1,t1,t1]

solve (Leaf a) = a
solve (Branch op ts) = op' $ map solve ts
        where op' = case op of
                        '+' -> sum
                        '*' -> product

-- testing
main = do
        print $ solve t1
        print $ solve t2
```

---

Testing

```
$ runghc t.hs 
104
1124864
```

Comment: This looks great as well but the other commenter gave a more concise answer. I appreciate the variation though! thank you

Comment: @user3487386 Yeah, defining operator type could make the implementation of `solve` looks much better.

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution looks like so:

```
solve (Leaf a) = a
solve (Branch f (t:ts)) = foldl' (\x -> f x . solve) (solve t) ts
```

Now you only need to map `Tree Int String` to `Tree Int (Int->Int->Int)`:

```
mapop (Branch "*" ts) = Branch (*) $ map mapop ts
mapop (Branch "+" ts) = Branch (+) $ map mapop ts
mapop (Leaf x) = Leaf x
```

So

```
> print $ solve $ mapop t1
104
```

But really `mapop` asks to derive Functor for Tree:

```
data Tree a b = Leaf a | Branch b [Tree a b] deriving (Eq,Show,Read,Functor)
mapop :: (Num a) => Tree a String -> Tree a (a->a->a)
mapop = fmap f where
  f "+" = (+)
  f "*" = (*)
```

Note that I am not assuming a `Monoid` here, because you didn't mention in your question what to do with empty lists in `Branch`.